# How do I resolve "elasticsearch error: 'byte'" in superset?

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-superset

I am using python 3.6.9 to install [Apache Superset](https://superset.apache.org/) and elasticsearch version 7.9.1. I have created doc with type as byte but I couldn't query the value in SQL LAB in a superset, getting the following error while querying,

ES index:

```
PUT /sample
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "age":    { "type": "integer" },  
      "email":  { "type": "keyword"  }, 
      "name":   { "type": "byte"  }     
    }
  }
}


PUT sample/_doc/1
{
  "age": "10",
  "email": "admin@superset.com",
  "name": "admin"
}
```

Superset SQL Query:

```
SELECT age, email, name FROM "default".sample LIMIT 100

Response:
elasticsearch error: 'byte'
```

It's returning a row when I query without a **name** field,

```
SELECT age, email FROM "default".sample LIMIT 100

Response:
age   email
10    admin@superset.com
```

How can I solve this byte error? Any inputs here really appreciated.[image]